# Screen overlapping issue after deeplinking

Tags: android, react-native, deep-linking

App Developed using: react-native

### Steps:

- Via default Message App, I opened my app via deep-link.
- OS prompt me the available apps from which I can handle that url.
- I selected MyApp & it opened successfully & navigated me to particular screen.
- I wanted to test other deep-link, So, I navigated back to MessageApp.

### Problem:

Now the default Message App is running as MyApp.

I tried killing apps from background, Both MyApp & Message App. But even after that MessageApp is still working as MyApp.

I had to restart the phone to get it work.

What can be the problem.